# How it's going on infinite times?

Tags: c, loops, char

I tried to understand the logic behind it but couldn't. What is happening behind the scene and how it's going on for infinite times?

```
    char j=1;
    while(j <= 255)
    {
        printf("%d", j);
        j = j+1;
    }
```

Comment: This does not go on for infinite time

Comment: Yes. The output will be just 1234.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce it

Comment: Sorry! It's 255 not just 5.

Comment: lol @ the edit ..

Comment: Edited code makes sense. `j` never reaches `255` because the type of variable `j` is **signed char**. if `j` was `127` and added `1` again, it would become `-128`.

Comment: @zmag -- `char` values may be treated as either `signed char` or `unsigned char` values, depending upon the implementation, but `j` has type `char` in the above code, not `signed char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C `char` may be signed or unsigned - that is implementation dependent. If `signed`, then the range (on most platforms) is -128 to +127 so always less than 255.

Changing the type as follows:

```
unsigned char j=1;
```

will remove the ambiguity.  But even then `j <= 255` will always be true on most common platforms because it can never be greater then 255.  In this case it will "wrap" to zero, so:

```
while(j != 0)
```

will work, or more simply and with no platform dependency issues, just change the type of `j` to `int`:

```
int j=1;
```

which makes much more sense.

Comment: `UCHAR_MAX` may be 255, in which case `j = j+1` will wrap around (if `char` is `unsigned`) and the `j <= 255` condition of the `while` loop will always be true.

Comment: If `char` is signed and eight bits, then `j+1` eventually exceeds the `char` range and the result of `j = j+1;` is implementation-defined. It may signal, so the loop may terminate.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ; For sure, but I am yet to see an implementation where that would happen.  As a systems level language, C implementations do not normally rely on system features such as signalling.  And to not behave in this way would break a great deal of existing code - which compiler developers also tend to avoid.  That said, as I suggest to remove all doubt and ambiguity, don't use a `char`.